# Como colocar um valor de input para ser analisado em uma Promise?

Tags: javascript, html, promises

"Crie uma função que recebe a idade de um usuário e retorna uma Promise que depois de 2
segundos retornará se usuário é maior ou não que 18 anos"

Quando abro a página depois de 2 segundos o resultado carrega mesmo sem eu ter inserido um valor. E logo após, quando coloco um valor (maior ou menor que 18) o resultado diz sempre que é menor.

O meu código:

```
function clicado() {
    var inputIdade = document.querySelector('input.idad').value;
    return inputIdade;
}

function checaIdade(idade) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        setTimeout (function() {
            if(idade > 18) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                reject();
            }
        }, 2000 );
    })
}

checaIdade(clicado())
    .then(function() {
        console.log("Maior que 18");
    })
    .catch(function() {
        console.log("Menor que 18");
});
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português :-) ... Mas qual o problema com o seu código? Aconteceu algum erro? Detalhe mais a sua pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado :) Então, quando abro a página depois de 2 segundos o resultado carrega mesmo sem eu ter inserido um valor. E logo após, quando coloco um valor (maior ou menor que 18) o resultado diz sempre que é menor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do jeito que fez, vc já está executando o **setTimeout()** por isso depois de 2 segundos já é mostrado o valor o que também faz o código sempre cair no **`catch()`** que seria o **reject()**, pois o valor está vazio, logo *nunca será maior que 18*. Repare que se envolver a **`execução da Promise`** no setTimeout() e inserir um valor chumbado no input, verá que será mostrado o console corretamente:

```js
function clicado() {
  var inputIdade = document.querySelector('input#idad').value;
  return inputIdade;
}

function checaIdade(idade) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (idade >= 18) {
      resolve();
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  })
}

setTimeout(() => {
  checaIdade(clicado())
  .then(function() {
    console.log("Maior que 18");
  })
  .catch(function() {
    console.log("Menor que 18");
  });
}, 2000)
```

```html
<input type="text" id="idad" value="36">
```

Agora se pretende mostrar o console com a idade que for inserida no input, vc pode adicionar um evento tipo **onblur()**, por exemplo, para fazer o `if/else` conforme o valor digitado:

```js
function clicado() {
  var inputIdade = document.querySelector('input#idad').value;
  return inputIdade;
}

function checaIdade(idade) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (idade >= 18) {
      resolve();
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  })
}

document.querySelector('input#idad').addEventListener('blur', () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    checaIdade(clicado())
    .then(function() {
      console.log("Maior que 18");
    })
    .catch(function() {
      console.log("Menor que 18");
    });
  }, 2000)
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="idad">
```

> OBS: Na condição tbm coloquei um maior ou igual 18, pq se for 18 já e maior de idade!